# mysql stored procedure works only if i have one row

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-workbench

I have created a stored procedure in order to delete multiple rows from different tables.
basically there is a main row and all the other connected by a foreign key.
when I call the  procedure  when there is one main row every thing works fine and the main row alone the other rows are gone.
but when there are more than one row, the stored procedure dosen't work.
(there are no foreign key crossing, meaning there can't be two main rows with the same FK some where).
if I remove all the rollbacks i get "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails", witch is weird because when I execute the same delete statement in the same order directly (no stored procedure) everything works fine even with multiple main rows.
any idea??
here is my stored procedure

```
    -- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Routine DDL
    -- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
    -- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DELIMITER $$

    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Tik_Del`(IN dell_id INT(11))
    BEGIN
    DECLARE hatan_id INT(11) DEFAULT -1;
    DECLARE cala_id INT(11) DEFAULT -1;
    DECLARE tashlum_id INT(11) DEFAULT -1;
    DECLARE teauda_id INT(11) DEFAULT -1;
    DECLARE haderacha_id INT(11) DEFAULT -1;
    DECLARE rav_mekadesh_id INT(11) DEFAULT -1;
    DECLARE pirtei_hatuna_id INT(11) DEFAULT -1;
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK;
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING ROLLBACK;
    START TRANSACTION;

    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
    SELECT `tikim`.`hatan_id`,
        `tikim`.`cala_id`,
        `tikim`.`taslum_id`,
        `tikim`.`teauda_id`,
        `tikim`.`hadracha_id`,
        `tikim`.`rav_mekadesh_id`,
        `tikim`.`pirtei_hatuna_id`
    INTO hatan_id,cala_id,tashlum_id,teauda_id,haderacha_id,rav_mekadesh_id,pirtei_hatuna_id
    FROM `ad120`.`tikim` WHERE `tik_id`=dell_id;

    DELETE FROM `ad120`.`tikim` WHERE `tik_id`=dell_id;

    DELETE FROM `ad120`.`haderachot` WHERE `haderacha_id`=haderacha_id;

    DELETE FROM `ad120`.`tashlumim` WHERE `tashlum_id`=tashlum_id;

    DELETE FROM `ad120`.`rav_mekadesh` WHERE `rav_mekadesh_id`=rav_mekadesh_id;

    DELETE FROM `ad120`.`pirtei_hatuna` WHERE `pirtei_hatuna_id`=pirtei_hatuna_id;

    Call Aish_Del(hatan_id);
    Call Aish_Del(cala_id);

    Call Teauda_Del(teauda_id);


    COMMIT;
    END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i don't know why but when i change it to this it works

```
    -- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Routine DDL
    -- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
    -- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DELIMITER $$

    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Tik_Del`(IN dell_id INT(11))
    BEGIN
    /*DECLARE hatan_id INT(11) DEFAULT -1;
    DECLARE cala_id INT(11) DEFAULT -1;
    DECLARE tashlum_id INT(11) DEFAULT -1;
    DECLARE teauda_id INT(11) DEFAULT -1;
    DECLARE haderacha_id INT(11) DEFAULT -1;
    DECLARE rav_mekadesh_id INT(11) DEFAULT -1;
    DECLARE pirtei_hatuna_id INT(11) DEFAULT -1;*/
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK;
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING ROLLBACK;
    set @hatan_id =-1;
    set @cala_id =-1;
    set @tashlum_id =-1;
    set @teauda_id =-1;
    set @haderacha_id=-1;
    set @rav_mekadesh_id =-1;
    set @pirtei_hatuna_id=-1;

    START TRANSACTION;

    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
    SELECT `tikim`.`hatan_id`,
        `tikim`.`cala_id`,
        `tikim`.`taslum_id`,
        `tikim`.`teauda_id`,
        `tikim`.`hadracha_id`,
        `tikim`.`rav_mekadesh_id`,
        `tikim`.`pirtei_hatuna_id`
    INTO         @hatan_id,@cala_id,@tashlum_id,@teauda_id,@haderacha_id,@rav_mekadesh_id,@pirtei_hatuna_id
    FROM `ad120`.`tikim` WHERE `tik_id`=dell_id;

    DELETE FROM `ad120`.`tikim` WHERE `tik_id`=dell_id;

    DELETE FROM `ad120`.`haderachot` WHERE `haderacha_id`=@haderacha_id;

    DELETE FROM `ad120`.`tashlumim` WHERE `tashlum_id`=@tashlum_id;

    DELETE FROM `ad120`.`rav_mekadesh` WHERE `rav_mekadesh_id`=@rav_mekadesh_id;

    DELETE FROM `ad120`.`pirtei_hatuna` WHERE `pirtei_hatuna_id`=@pirtei_hatuna_id;

    Call Aish_Del(@hatan_id);
    Call Aish_Del(@cala_id);

    Call Teauda_Del(@teauda_id);


    COMMIT;
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing a multi-table DELETE?

```
DELETE k, h, t, r, p 
FROM `ad120`.`tikim` AS k
LEFT OUTER JOIN `ad120`.`haderachot` AS h USING (`hadracha_id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `ad120`.`tashlumim` AS t USING (`tashlum_id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `ad120`.`rav_mekadesh` AS r USING (`rav_mekadesh_id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `ad120`.`pirtei_hatuna` AS p USING (`pirtei_hatuna_id`)
WHERE k.`tik_id` = dell_id;
```

Another alternative is to declare all the foreign keys using `ON DELETE CASCADE`.  Then you can just delete from `tikim` and let the rest cascade (I'm assuming that `tikim` is the parent referenced by all the other tables).